# 'Illegal instruction'

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-natty, roboearth, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a problem with loading and saving models, always return text 'Illegal instruction'.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 electric and all was install and run by tutorials.

Perception-pcl-addons from repository as 'ros-electric-perception-pcl-addons'.

```
// SAVE
...
writing /tmp/object_recorder_0/Can.Energy_drink_can/face_000.png[ INFO]
[1320658625.942711015]: Received PointCloud
[ INFO] [1320658626.933096772]: Received PointCloud
Illegal instruction

// LOAD
...
[ INFO] [1320458961.172944345]: model path callback; path=/home/user/models/videogame.Videogamecover_kinect
[ INFO] [1320458961.242162236]: loading model aspect: /home/user/models/videogame.Videogamecover_kinect/dense_face_028.pcd
Illegal instruction
```

Thanks for any help, Jan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11821/%27illegal-instruction%27/) by [jansvec](https://answers.ros.org/users/1281/jansvec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-07**:
What are the hardware specifications of your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the backtrace. This looks like another manifestation of http://answers.ros.org/question/2839/illegal-instruction-when-using-image_view-with. Updating your system to the most recent OpenCV package should solve it.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3